# how this sample Forged digital certificate

Tags: certificate, portable-executable, pki, faker, digital

I found a pe file，when i check digital certificate，i found winxp can identity the digital cert，but win10   can not，virus total also show that this file is not signd

Is this a fake digital cert？
how to made this happen？

winxp info：

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f4QVg.png)
win10 info

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5M2S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Windows XP used SHA1 hashes in the signatures, which is not supported on 10:

[Source](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/109629/deprecation-of-sha1-code-signing-certificates-on-windows):

The following table shows which OS's support SHA-1 and SHA-256 code signatures:

```
+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
|     Windows OS      |             SHA-1             |           SHA-256            |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
| XP SP3, Server 2003 | Yes                           | No (need KB968730, KB938397) |
| Vista, Server 2008  | Yes                           | No (need KB2763674)          |
| 7, Server 2008 R2   | No (if signed after 1/1/2016) | Yes (with latest updates)    |
| 8.1, Server 2012 R2 | No (if signed after 1/1/2016) | Yes                          |
| 10, Server 2016     | No (if signed after 1/1/2016) | Yes                          |
+---------------------+-------------------------------+------------------------------+
```